# Relating Temperature and Battery Performance (HELP)

Tags: batteries, physics, battery-chemistry

I am a grade 11 student performing a experiment on relating how external temperature affects the performance of a battery, so its voltage and current change. I've done so much research and cant find a formula that relates temperature to any parameters of a battery. The experiment plan is to get a battery and discharge it at different temperatures but the problem is that I need to have a theoretical formula that supports the results. Could any of you please help find some formulas that I could use. Thank You.

Comment: What battery? does it have a model #?

Comment: Lithium Ion Polymer Battery - 3.7v 100mAh

Comment: `I need to have a theoretical formula that supports the results` .... what if the results of a carefully conducted experiment do not match the formula?

Comment: Nothing really, It can be blamed on sources of error and other factors in the unideal conditions. I just need a way to calculate and determine the trend.

Answer (score 1):

LiPo batteries have a nonlinear behaviour with temperature and varies widely with quality of construction, although there are some generalizations.

Assumptions

- Battery model specifications take precedence over generic expectations
- test with controlled constant current sink vs voltage must not stay under/over voltage for any significant time.
- if specs define capacity and charge cycle life, these will affect temperature results
- several batteries must be tested to determine standard deviation of the experiment
- [example specs](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/1570/1570datasheet.pdf)

  - [image]
- search ["google images"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Li-Polymer%20temperature%20performance%20graphs&client=firefox-b-e&sxsrf=ALeKk03u89BdnqLLcglrDJqvfPQUokUp1Q:1613004931072&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=A674IQCkY-WZzM%252CGOHWjmw-lOs3uM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRaUdDG-XhgjCtAhGdc88YLes48ew&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr0r_Pz-DuAhUFCKwKHWTEBkEQ9QF6BAgIEAE) for 100mA LiPo temperature performance graphs
- search [battery university site](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures) for experience
- search "Google Scholar, Microsoft Academic" [Research-gate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330142356_Optimal_Operational_Planning_of_Scalable_DC_Microgrid_with_Demand_Response_Islanding_and_Battery_Degradation_Cost_Considerations/figures?lo=1)
  [image]
- define test specs, test methods ( dry ice, thermometer, test point, self-heating), measurement intervals, estimate an acceptance criteria, choose CC sink design, automate test
- have fun

Comment: Thanks I am starting to understand, although is there any specific equation I can use to determine the amount of power it could deliver at -10 C rather than at 10 C

Comment: Looking at the graph it drops from 90% to 65%. Can you use a spreadsheet with curve fit?